# When I run my program (in C) several times it always chooses the same random numbers

Tags: c

So my program is effectively a DPLL SAT solver, therefore inside the program it needs to choose random variables to assign TRUE or FALSE to. If I run my once program it works fine!If if run it again it will choose different variables and still work (this is what I want).

However to produce reliable experiments I need to do repeat runs of my program. This could be done by running the program multiple times separately, but this is tedious and will take too long. I have learnt how to use bash as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash 

for ((i=50; i>0; i--))  
do  
./Project 90 10 >> outfile.txt 
done
```

However when this is done, every run picks the same 'random' variables in the same order and so produces the same results. How can I make my program run differently each time??

Thanks!!

Comment: You're asking us to debug a program that you did not show to us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialize the random number seed, random numbers are not really random, add this to your `main()`

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    srand(time(NULL)); /* here at the very beginnig of main */
    .
    .
    .
    return 0;
}
```

this will give a different seed every time the program is executed, since `time(NULL)` will return a different value.

Read [this](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?srand+3) for more information.

**Note**: as commented by [Ingo Leonhardt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2470782/ingo-leonhardt) the effect will be the same, so try this option

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);

    srand(tv.tv_usec); /* here at the very beginnig of main */
    .
    .
    .
    return 0;
}
```

or, since every process will have a different `pid` this could also work<sup>1</sup>

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    srand((int)getpid()); /* here at the very beginnig of main */
    .
    .
    .
    return 0;
}
```

---

1<sub>This is a POSIX solution, if you want you can research what is your OS equivalent if it doesn't support POSIX.</sub>

Comment: in a shell loop like above, `time(NULL)` will return the same number of seconds for several calls

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt , So what would you suggest to seed it?

Comment: @CoolGuy one could make use of the microseconds returned by `gettimeofday()` and somehow combine them with `seconds % ...` or getpid() or ...; On linux you could also read from /dev/random

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt that was exactly what I was thinking I will update the answer.

Comment: Thank you!!  I had already tried to use srand(NULL) and it wasn't working but srand(tv.tv_usec)  fixed it thanks!!@IngoLeonhardt @iharob

Comment: @Ryry be careful, `srand(NULL)` is wrong, if you enable compiler warnings the compiler will complain, although it's equivalent to `srand(0)` which means you where not really changing the seed, and `srand(time(NULL));` has a problem because it returns a value with seconds precision, and of course you will execute the program several times in one second, so the method that worked, worked because it has μs precision.